# bloom filter: how to estimate probability and tune the filter

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

My goal is to tune [bloom filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter) in such a way so that I'd get best possible results.

I have a dictionary of N=100000 strings, and I have distinct sets of strings S0, S1, S2. For each string from these three sets I need to guess if the string is part of the dictionary. The goal is to get highest possible guess for total of all elements from union of the three sets S0+S1+S2.

That's basically what the bloom filter does. Now, I'm limited to how much memory can be used by my bloom filter (e.g. I can have only 100000 buckets, or 1 bit per element of the dictionary). According to [bloom filter calculator](http://hur.st/bloomfilter?n=100000&p=0.618505) 100000 bits should give around 38.1495% probability to guess correctly for 100000 elements.
The approximation formula for bloom filter is:

```
bits = ceil((N * log(1-P)) / log(1.0 / (pow(2.0, log(2.0)))));
```

where N is number of elements of the dictionary, and P is probability to guess correctly (from 0 to 1).

If I didn't know anything about elements from S0, S1, S2 I'd have no choice but to create simple bloom filter for entire dictionary and I'd get something around 38% correct answers. However, I know that S0 contains only strings with 6-char length, S1 contains only strings with 7-char length, S2 contains only strings with 8-char length (entire dictionary contains only 6,7,8 char long string also). Probability of a string from S0 to be part of dictionary is X, for S1 and S2 probabilities are Y and Z.

Given this information, and constrains (e.g. 100000 bit memory) what's the best approach to get best possible match?
Assume, that dictionary contains N6 strings with length 6, N7 with length 7 and N8 with length 8, e.g. N6+N7+N8 = 100000, and sets S0, S1, S2 have X0, X1, X2 elements.

For example, if dictionary contained 50000 strings of length 6 and the rest was 7 and 8 char long string, and if S0 (set with 6-char length strings) had 80% probability of any of its elements to be part of dictionary, and S1 and S2 had 10% and 20% probability, then perhaps it's better to assume for all elements from S0 that they are part of dictionary (e.g. I'd get 20% wrong) and construct bloom filter for remaining 50000 elements from the dictionary and test only elements from S1 and S2. This way I'd perhaps get overall best possible detection rate. Note, that bloom filter returns if an element is not in the dictionary or it might be in the dictionary, eg. it cannot have false negatives. In my algorithm I don't care if I can return false negatives, my goal is to simply get most of elements from combined union guessed correctly.

Another example, imagine that S0 had 5 elements, S1 had 50000, S2 had 60000. If dictionary had 50000 6-char long strings, then obviously it's better to assume that elements from S0 are part of the dictionary (or not part), and construct bloom filter only for the rest 50000 strings from the dictionary.